# Phone stuck in bootloop and recovery not working

Tags: boot-loop, unbricking, lg-g6

TLDR: I wanted to root my LG G6 (H780) so I unlocked the bootloader, flashed TWRP, then SuperSU and now it's stuck in a bootloop and the recovery isn't working.

Unlocking the bootloader itself was as easy and gave me zero problems. Flashing TWRP was also easy however I did initially have a problem with it: it asked for a password to decrypt the storage even though (afaik) I had turned the encryption off. After some searching I found out that this might be a bug with the version that I used so I found a more up to date one for my phone. This time it didn't ask me for a password and I was even able to flash SuperSU. After flashing SuperSU I wanted to reboot my phone, and it's now stuck in a bootloop. If I try to go into recovery I get the 2 prompt that ask you if you are sure you want to delete all user data but after that, it just goes back into the bootloop.

I was wondering if anyone has any idea if there is even anything that I can do. I can't get it into recovery so I can't even use ADB (afaik). Thanks for your help.

I have seen other similar questions about this but I believe they are specifically for that phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to start Download mode and use LG Bridge as shown in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JNAvoq3Dr6U) video.

I wanted to try this before, but I wasn't able to get into Download mode. The time window to hold volume up and plug in the cable it pretty small.